# Can anyone cite some resources for permutations and combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am highly interested in learning permutations and combinations. Sorry, if this question has been asked before, but below are some points that how I would like to study this subject ?

- I want to start from definition of permutations and combinations that where order matters and does not matter.
- I want some simple problems which help me learn the basics and help me improve
- After all, I would like to dig deep in this subject and solve some tough problems in it
- I would like to learn some new theorems which are used to solve tough problems in an easy way such as sterling formula of second kind.

---

Please kindly help me to provide reference of any standard book or any online source or anything which basically helps to build humble confidence in this subject.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest Combinatorics: Topics, Techniques, Algorithms by Peter J Cameron

A book which helps you easily solve Sterling number of second kind is Generating functionology by Herbert Wilff